# Robot.getPixelColor vs BufferedImage.getRGB

Tags: java, awtrobot

I am asking this today for the purpose of comparing the two.

What I am trying to do is make a bot that is able to click the space-bar at a certain time.

Anyway, let me show what I am trying to compare.

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
```

This will be out Robot. (java.awt.Robot;)

My question is, which is faster for the purpose of try to constantly read one (or more) pixels on the screen at once?

My current (in progress) programs that are the same with the exception of one using

`Robot.getPixelColor(int, int)`

and the other uses

```
BufferedImage image Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)
imaage.getRGB
```

These are being run at many times a second, and I am simply trying to figure out which is more consistently faster. They both seem random at the speed at which they operate, so any advice is appreciated.

In case you wish for an example to put these into, here is the setup for it.

Here is the example using Robot.getPixelColor(int, int)

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    Point prompt = new Point(913, 506, robot);
    BufferedImage screenImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);    
    for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
        zones.add(new Point(radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) + centerX, radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) + centerY, robot));
    }
    System.out.println("Resolution: "  + width + " * " + height/* + " " + robot.getPixelColor(20, 20)/* + " " + screenImage.getRGB((int) prompt.getX(), (int) prompt.getY())*/);
    while(true) {
        tempZone = null;
        while(prompt.hasColor(promptColor)) {
            System.out.println("Found prompt, trying to find zone.");
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < zones.size(); i++) {
                if(zones.get(i).hasColor(zoneColor)){
                    tempZone = zones.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(tempZone != null) {
                System.out.println("Found zone at: " + tempZone.getX() + ", " + tempZone.getY() + ". Looking for ticker...");
                tempZone.whenHasColor(zoneColor);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unable to find zone.");
            }
            while(prompt.hasColor(promptColor)) {}
        }
    }
```

With its Point Class:

```
public class Point {    
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private final Robot robot;

    public Point(double x, double y, Robot rob) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.robot = rob;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public boolean hasColor(Color color) {
        return (robot.getPixelColor((int )x, (int) y).equals(color));
    }
    public void whenHasColor(Color color) throws IOException {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(889 + (int) x, 449 + (int) y, 1, 1);
        while(hasColor(color)) {
            //Nothing
        }
        BufferedImage cap = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
        if(Math.abs(Math.abs(cap.getRGB(0, 0)) - 15657182) < 350000) {
            System.out.println("Missed Zone, failure.");
        }else {
            robot.keyPress(Main.promptKey);
            System.out.println("Found ticker pressing key. ");
        }
    }
}
```

For anyone wondering where could something this specific come from, I am using a modified version of [this website](http://www.mistersyms.com/tools/gitgud/) as my medium for making this bot.

Now for the example with using Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle) and BufferedImage.getRGB(int, int)

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(889, 449, 149, 149); 
    Point prompt = new Point(24, 57, robot);
    String format = "png";
    String fileName = "fullDebug1." + format;       
    BufferedImage screenImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);    
    for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
        zones.add(new Point(radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) + centerX, radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) + centerY, robot));
    }
    System.out.println("Resolution: "  + width + " * " + height/* + " " + screenImage.getRGB((int) prompt.getX(), (int) prompt.getY())*/);
    while(true) {
        tempZone = null;
        int zoneFinal = 0;
        while(prompt.hasColor(promptColor)) {
            System.out.println("Found prompt, trying to find zone.");
            BufferedImage zoneImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
            int count = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < zones.size(); i++) {
                if(zones.get(i).hasColorZones(zoneColor, zoneImage)){
                    tempZone = zones.get(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(tempZone != null) {
                System.out.println("Found zone at: " + tempZone.getX() + ", " + tempZone.getY() + ". Looking for ticker...");
                tempZone.whenHasColor(zoneColor);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unable to find zone.");
            }
            while(prompt.hasColor(promptColor)) {}
        }
```

and its Point class:

```
public class Point {    
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private final Robot robot;

    public Point(double x, double y, Robot rob) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.robot = rob;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public boolean hasColor(int color) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(889, 449, 149, 149);
        BufferedImage screenImage = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
        return (Math.abs(screenImage.getRGB((int) x, (int) y)) == Math.abs(color))
    }
    public boolean hasColorPixel(int color, Rectangle rect) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage cap = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
        return Math.abs(cap.getRGB(0, 0)) == Math.abs(color);
    }

    public boolean hasColorZones(int color, BufferedImage screenImage) {
        return Math.abs(screenImage.getRGB((int) x, (int) y)) == Math.abs(color);
    }

    public boolean hasColorList(int[] colors, BufferedImage screenImage) {
        for(int i : colors) {
            if(Math.abs(screenImage.getRGB((int) x, (int) y)) == Math.abs(i)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void whenHasColor(int color) throws IOException {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(889 + (int) x, 449 + (int) y, 1, 1);
        while(hasColorPixel(color, rect)) {
            //Nothing
        }
        BufferedImage cap = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
        if(Math.abs(Math.abs(cap.getRGB(0, 0)) - 15657182) < 350000) {
            System.out.println("Missed Zone, failure.");
        }else {
            robot.keyPress(Main.promptKey);
            System.out.println("Found ticker pressing key. ");
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, which will run faster? Sometimes the latter option (which I more thoroughly debugged) gets 10 in a row, but then will fail randomly too. At first I thought it was that my laptop could not handle it, but upon running it on my desktop I had the same results. I would rather not have the bot be inconsistent with working properly or not.

I do hope I was able to give enough information for anyone to be able to help me. If there is anything I need to add or change, please tell me! This is my first question and I would like to learn to be better with this site.
Another apologies to if 1) the pixels are not the same on your screen, therefore you would not be able to run this to simulate my situation, and 2) if this post was long. I wanted to make a good "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example," but I wasn't sure how to shorten it any more.

**EDIT**

To make the code put in more relevant, as Ben pointed out, I could have cut it. But I thought of something that makes it more useful.

What can be done to that code to optimize it to run faster, so the bot will be 100% consistently working, or at least closer to 100% than it is now (~60%)

Comment: If you look in the implementation of `Robot` you will find that `getPixelColor()` internally calls `peer.getRGBPixel()` for the point specified. `createScreenCapture` does the same for all pixels in the rectangle. As this includes integrity checks on the rectangle and so on, in theory `getPixelColor()` should be faster. In reality the difference will probably be neglectable.

Comment: Also as a sidenote regarding your MCVE problem: You could have simply created 2 examples with 2 steps each: 1.) Create a robot. 2.) Call `getPixelColor` or `createScreenCapture`. Everything else in your code is basically noise that's not important for the question (and in all honesty probably isn't read by anyone). You want to "provide as much as needed but not any more" basically. And here what is needed really only is: 1.) The methods you are trying to compare. 2.) What you have already tried to compare them.

Comment: +Ben, this is a good point, and I probably could have done that. I am adding another part to the question now that will probably make the whole thing more useful. But as for MCVEs go, yeah I probably could have cut out most of it :P